# Trying to build an movie website, but Movie poster doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to put images on Movie app but looks like it doesn't work.

I totally have no idea where I'm doing wrong in code.

So, is there anyone who can help me find the wrong parts?

Thank you !

inside of App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Movie from './Movie';

const movieTitles = [
  "Matrix",
  "Full Metal Jacket",
  "Oldboy",
  "Star Wars"
]

const movieImages = [
  "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNzQzOTk3OTAtNDQ0Zi00ZTVkLWI0MTEtMDllZjNkYzNjNTc4L2ltYWdlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNjU0OTQ0OTY@._V1_.jpg",
  "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNzkxODk0NjEtYjc4Mi00ZDI0LTgyYjEtYzc1NDkxY2YzYTgyXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzkwMjQ5NzM@._V1_.jpg",
  "https://file.mk.co.kr/meet/neds/2016/08/image_readtop_2016_598718_14719314482590048.jpg",
  "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51bvrRm3toL._SY445_.jpg"
]

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Movie title={movieTitles[0]} poster={movieImages[0]} />
        <Movie title={movieTitles[1]} poster={movieImages[1]} />
        <Movie title={movieTitles[2]} poster={movieImages[2]} />
        <Movie title={movieTitles[3]} poster={movieImages[3]} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

in Movie.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Movie.css';

class Movie extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <MoviePoster poster={this.props.poster} />
                <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class MoviePoster extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <img src={this.props.posetr} />
        )
    }
}

export default Movie;
```

Those are what I wrote. If there's someone who could help me, I would really appreciate it! Thank you.

Comment: `<img src={this.props.posetr} />` there's a typo in `poster`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MoviePoster extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <img src={this.props.posetr} />
        )
    }
}
```

You wrote posetr instead of poster)